# In JPA, if we have a OneToMany or ManyToMany that is mappedBy one entity, do we need to update both in the setters?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, jpa, spring-data-jpa

Let's say we have Teacher and Student tables

One teacher, Many students.

The relationship can be seen as below.

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "teacher")
public class Teacher {

    @OneToMany(mappedBy="teacher")
    private Set<Student> student = new HashSet<>();

    }
}
```

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "student")
public class Student {

    @ManyToOne
    private Teacher teacher;

}
```

Say we got a new student like so:

```
Student student = new Student();
```

Would I need to update and save on both the teacher and student like this:

```
teacher.getStudent().add(student);
student.setTeacher(teacher);
teacherRepository.save(teacher);
studentRepository.save(student);
```

Or would it be ok just to save the student?

Now what if it's many to many?

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "teacher")
public class Teacher {

    @ManyToMany(mappedBy="teacher")
    private Set<Student> student = new HashSet<>();

    }
}
```

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "student")
public class Student {

    @ManyToMany
    @JoinTable(
            name="teacher_student",
            joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "teacher_id"),
            inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "student_id")
    )
    private Set<Teacher> teacher = new HashSet<>();

}
```

Would I be ok to just save from the student side for this?

What happens if you save from the teacher side as well before saving from the student side?

For example

```
teacherRepository.save(teacher)
student.setTeacher(teacher);
studentRepository.save(student);
```

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I create and use the following convenience method.

```
@Entit
@Table(name = "student")
public class Student {

    @ManyToOne
    private Teacher teacher;

    ...
    public void setTeacher(Teacher teacher) {
        this.teacher = teacher;
        teacher.getStudnet().add(this);
    }
}
```